# mysql database connection in java netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am trying to develop a simple database web application in netbeans, but I am getting a problem at database connection , my database is not being connected for some reason, the username password and hostname are correct and the mysql workbench is registered with my netbeans as well.

Is there something wrong with this code?

```
public class test {    
public static void main(String args[]) {        
Connection conn=null;    
try{    `conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud_news", "root","zunairaabira");`    
if(conn!=null){    
System.out.println("successful");   
 }    }
catch(Exception e){    System.out.println("notconnected");    
}}}
```

please help!!

Comment: Please give us some specific error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call instance of the mysql driver too. Add

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

before Your conn= statement.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't loaded the MYSQL JDBC Driver.

Add this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver").newInstance();
```